# Turning strings into commands?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is there a convenient way to take variables and convert them into something readable by the code? What I have right now reads somewhat like this:

```
int buttonNumber = 3;
int buttonShow = 0;
ButtonChanger bC;

void Update () {
    if(buttonNumber == 1) {
        buttonShow = bC.Change1;
    }
    if(buttonNumber == 2) {
        buttonShow = bC.Change2;
    }
    if(buttonNumber == 3) {
        buttonShow = bC.Change3;
    }
```

What I would like to be able to do is more like this:

```
int buttonNumber = 3;
int buttonShow = 0;
ButtonChanger bC;

void Update () {
    buttonShow = ("bC.Change" + buttonNumber).toCode();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    enum ButtonChanger
    {
        Change1 = 1,
        Change2 = 2,
        Change3 = 3
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var changer = GetButtonChanger(2);

            Console.WriteLine(changer);
            Console.WriteLine((int)changer);
        }

        private static ButtonChanger GetButtonChanger(int i)
        {
            return (ButtonChanger)Enum.Parse(typeof(ButtonChanger), string.Format("Change{0}", i));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try using Dictionary<>. It will allow you to have key value pair. so your key would be bC.Change and you can retrive key using Key() method

eg

```
Dictionary<string, int> data = new Dictionary<string, int>();
data.Add("Change1", 123);
data.Add("Change2", 456);
foreach (string key in data.Keys)
{
    Console.WriteLine(key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand you right but given your title *... into commands* I assume you are looking for a generic way to execute the methods in ButtonChanger.

If your `ButtonChanger` class is of type `Component` or `GameObject` you can use the [SendMessage](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GameObject.SendMessage.html) method:

**MyClass.cs**

```
const string ButtonShowPrefix = "Change";
ButtonChanger bC;

void Update () {
    bC.SendMessage (ButtonShowPrefix + buttonNumber, SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
}
```

**ButtonChanger.cs**

```
void Change1 () {
    // do stuff for button 1
}

void Change2 () {
    // do stuff for button 2
}
```

Note that it is possible to pass a parameter to the called method but there is no way to return a value. So if you need state information you have to work around this by using a public member in `ButtonChanger`.

As `SendMessage` is considered as somewhat expensive you should avoid unnecessary calls in case that no action has to be taken.

If things are getting more complex I would suggest combining this with gulshanm01 approach of using a dictionary for mapping identifiers to methods.